# Как удалить добавленный класс при повторном клике?

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой код для переключения активного класса:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
cards.forEach(card => {
  const button = card.querySelector('.card__title');
  const image = card.querySelector('.card__image');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    // Удаляем классы у активных элементов
    cards.forEach(n => n.querySelector('.card__image').classList.remove('active'));
    
    // Добавляем текущему элементу
    image.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500&display=swap&subset=cyrillic');

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color:#2C2C2C;
}
.row {
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #252525;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACMAAAAjCAQAAAC00HvSAAAAqUlEQVR4AaXTIa7EMBBEwfrSAAODwAUfGBiY5P7H26XDIqXfAUrpseI520fcAf+itgEqgW4TMugoCKA2J4DanAQ6CgKozYmg44IMuhVk0FaQQceEDLoNyKBtQAZtExKozQkot7Dv37e42rqoaUk6Koe21ngJLYMManN6034xJzz2UnqvvugY+fNvIIOWIoW24aHnG20V/yJtTgAtAyKozQmgpURdLp+nOT9tfAyifaRWFwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    width: 33.33333%;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    background-color: #080808;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.card__image {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 5px groove #252525;
  height: 220px;
}

.active {
    filter: invert(1);
}

.card__image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card__title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #b3b3b3;
    font-weight: 800;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}


.card__title:hover {
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="card">
<div class="card__image">
<img src="https://7img.net/users/4015/27/77/89/album/pr/movie610_800x600.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
</div>
<span class="card__title">Button</span>   
</div>


<div class="card">
<div class="card__image">
<img src="https://7img.net/users/4015/27/77/89/album/pr/movie610_800x600.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
</div>
<span class="card__title">Button</span>   
</div>



<div class="card">
<div class="card__image">
<img src="https://7img.net/users/4015/27/77/89/album/pr/movie610_800x600.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
</div>
<span class="card__title">Button</span>   
</div>

</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить добавленный класс при повторном клике ?

Несколько дней уже ломаю голову как это реализовать и всё безуспешно... При клике на Button - активный класс добавляется к изображению, но при повторном клике на Button - активный класс не снимается, хотя и поставил .classList.toggle(), так как думал что он снимет активный класс при повторном клике, но почему-то не сработало.

Мне удалось переключать активный класс, но как его всё таки снять при повторном клике?

Comment: Попробуйте не использовать foreach, используйте обычный цикл for. Вы плохо понимаете как используется foreach, поэтому ошибки

Comment: Попытался обычным циклом, не помогает. Наоборот всё перестало работать

Comment: `cards.forEach(n => n.querySelector('.card__image').classList.remove('active'));` - Здесь вы удаляете класс у всех картинок. Они все не активные становятся. `image.classList.toggle('active');`  - здесь вы добавляете кликнутому элементу активный класс. Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин при чем тут цикл? Можете объяснить, почему ТС не правильно цикл использует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо удалять активный класс у элементов, кроме кликнутого.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
cards.forEach(card => {
  const button = card.querySelector('.card__title');
  const image = card.querySelector('.card__image');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    const activeСards = document.querySelectorAll('.card .card__image.active');
    // Удаляем классы у активных элементов, кроме текущего
    activeСards.forEach(n => n !== image ? n.classList.remove('active') : null);

    // Добавляем текущему элементу
    image.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500&display=swap&subset=cyrillic');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #2C2C2C;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #252525;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACMAAAAjCAQAAAC00HvSAAAAqUlEQVR4AaXTIa7EMBBEwfrSAAODwAUfGBiY5P7H26XDIqXfAUrpseI520fcAf+itgEqgW4TMugoCKA2J4DanAQ6CgKozYmg44IMuhVk0FaQQceEDLoNyKBtQAZtExKozQkot7Dv37e42rqoaUk6Koe21ngJLYMManN6034xJzz2UnqvvugY+fNvIIOWIoW24aHnG20V/yJtTgAtAyKozQmgpURdLp+nOT9tfAyifaRWFwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  width: 33.33333%;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2C2C2C;
  background-color: #080808;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.card__image {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5px groove #252525;
  height: 220px;
}

.active {
  filter: invert(1);
}

.card__image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.card__title:hover {
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__image">
      <img src="https://7img.net/users/4015/27/77/89/album/pr/movie610_800x600.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
    </div>
    <span class="card__title">Button</span>
  </div>


  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__image">
      <img src="https://7img.net/users/4015/27/77/89/album/pr/movie610_800x600.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
    </div>
    <span class="card__title">Button</span>
  </div>



  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__image">
      <img src="https://7img.net/users/4015/27/77/89/album/pr/movie610_800x600.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
    </div>
    <span class="card__title">Button</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо! работает!